# Break up inline-block elements

Tags: html, css

What I want to do is break up the inline-block `<li>`s. The code is generated and I have no access to it before it is written to the page. Because the `<li>` elements have no white space between them, they are not split and won't justify across the page.

I don't mind if the solution is CSS or Javascript based.

I have tried various things in CSS 'content:' and 'after:'.

Please see this fiddle for a demo of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/2L56N/5/

Edit: The result should like the top example. However, the generated code is like in the bottom example (no space between the tags, causing the inline-block to become one). Drag the width over so only 2 images show to see the justify effect I am looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you be a bit more specific how the end result should look like?

Comment: Added an edit, hopefully it makes more sense now

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, you can simply add margins to the `li` elements like so:

```
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B7cL9/

Comment: That does look better, but what I am looking for is for the <li> elements to justify across the page. See the edit to my original post

Comment: @MarkTickner Adding `margin-right:5px;` seems to make them match up nicely: http://jsfiddle.net/Yd8NH/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but what I am looking to do is justify the items rather than hard-code padding or widths

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:flex;` with `justify-content:space-between;` to simulate your `text-align:justify` *when white space are missing in between your inline boxes* this will only work for younger browsers
:

```
ul {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    text-align: justify;/* your code */
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;/* your code */
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2L56N/6/)**